# Pattern matching in GitHub GraphQL query

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm trying to query the branch protection rules which has the similar patterns using wildcards. Any suggestion are welcome.

```
query {
  repository(owner:"user",name: "repo") {
    branchProtectionRules(first: 10) {
      nodes {
          pattern
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

O/P:

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "branchProtectionRules": {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "release"
                    },
                    {
                        "pattern": "release-220"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to find the pattern fields with release*

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue got fixed:

[image: Query with output in GitHub GraphQL Explorer]